# MVC 4 authorization with android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, authorization

Im creating ASP.NET MVC 4 services and an android app. 
I want to authorize my requests in the android app to the MVC 4 controller using facebook sdk or form based authentication. 
How can i achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login the user on your Android app and get them to approve the app. Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/) for a quick tutorial on how to do that.

After that process you would have obtained an Access token for the user. You would now need to POST this to your MVC web service using probably a REST call, probably POST to transmit the data in HTTP headers and store the access token and facebook ID of the user in your Model. With this you will have the details of the authenticated user which you can then use to make calls to Facebook's Graph API.